# Why Can't I Create a WAS 8.5 server profile or server within RSA (RSA4WS) 9.5?

Tags: websphere-8, ibm-rad

I recently installed Rational Software Architect Designer for WebSphere Software (RSA4WS) 9.5. I am trying to create a WAS 8.5 server within RSA, but...

- The version of Profile Management Tool that RSA launches is 7.0
- The only WAS installed runtime that RSA recognizes is WAS 7.0
- Although the New Server dialog lists WAS 7.0, 8.0 and 8.5...

  - When I select WAS 7.0, the Server Runtime Environment dropdown list is set to WAS v7.0
  - When I select either WAS 8.0 or WAS 8.5, the Server Runtime Environment dropdown list is set to "Create a new runtime environment"
- Under Window | Preferences, Server | Runtime Environments, RSA lists:

  - Web Preview Server Runtime
  - WebSphere Application Server v7.0
  - WebSphere Application Server v8.0 stub
  - WebSphere Application Server v8.5 stub
- The subdirectories of C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes are:

  - base_stub
  - base_v7
  - base_v7_stub
  - base_v8_stub
  - base_v85_stub
  - nodejs
  - updi_v7X_64
  - wsdk

I suspect that I haven't installed some feature set for RSA, but I've not found any downloads on IBM's Passport Advantage site that seem like they'd be what I would need. Since RSA4WS is basically Rational Application Developer (RAD) plus extra stuff, maybe downloading a package for RAD would do the trick -- but I don't know whether that's the case.

To complicate matters, for security reasons, my development PC is not Internet-connected, so I have to guess which downloads I need, download them, transfer the files to the development PC, and point Installation Manager to the (local) repository.

Does anyone have any advice? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install WAS 8.5.5.x runtime separately. WAS 8.x testing environment is no longer included in the RAD/RSA installation itself.
You can either:

- download additional files with 8.5.5.x runtime from Passport Advantage labeled `IBM WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5 (x of 3) for Multiplatform Multilingual`
- or just download WAS 8.5.5.x for developers from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ws/wasdevelopers/)